# Firebase Query to RecycleView Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a query that shows some information from firebase but the result is an Object and I can't add and show it in a `RecyclerView` from Android. I can see the result using `System.out.println()`; but I can´t see on the `RecyclerView`. Someone knows how to do it?

```
public Libros(String autor_Libro, String titulo_Libro) { 
    Autor_Libro = autor_Libro; Titulo_Libro = titulo_Libro; 
}
```

And in main activity have:

```
ArrayList<Libros>librosArrayList=new ArrayList<>(); 
librosArrayList.add(new Libros("Eduardo Mendoza", "La verdad sobre el Caso Savolta")); 
RecyclerView contenedor=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Contenedor); 
contenedor.setAdapter(new Adaptador(librosArrayList));
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: I just delete because i'm trying to convert using String.valueOf(Object).
In a general case.How can I show firebase query on a recycleView insede a card view?

Comment: Depends on the object. You need to create de POJO and then populate the recyclerview

Comment: I have a constructor like that
 public Libros(String autor_Libro, String titulo_Libro) {
        Autor_Libro = autor_Libro;
        Titulo_Libro = titulo_Libro;
    }
And in main activity have 

        ArrayList<Libros>librosArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
              librosArrayList.add(new Libros("Eduardo Mendoza", "La verdad sobre el Caso Savolta"));
RecyclerView contenedor=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Contenedor);
contenedor.setAdapter(new Adaptador(librosArrayList));

Comment: You need to create the object in the firebase onValue listener

Comment: and how to do that? with a method or how?

Comment: Check to see if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50918372/9167710